# TextView adding a variable string and appending another

Tags: android-edittext, edit

I am using IntentExtra to pass three variables from an entry in a RecyclerView from one Activity  into a TextView on another Activity (ActivityTwo) using Get Extras. That all works fine and the variables are joined and  displayed in the TextView.

```
   TextView mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewOrderList);

        mTitle.append(number +  title + (Double) price);
```

I then navigate back to ActivityOne, select a different item in the RecyclerView and the new variables are sent to ActivityTwo.

However, despite using append, it either a/ overwrites the existing text, OR b/the first set of text is not retained. Am not sure which

I did consider saving the text to a local file and then appending to it each time I enter ActivityTwo. Then loading it into the TextView But this feels like using a steamroller to crack a nut!!

Any solutions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to write to a local file. As I wanted to Append info rather than overwrite I used the MODE_APPEND rather than MODE_PRIVATE.

```
      try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileTitle,MODE_APPEND);
                fOut.write(dataTitle.getBytes());
                fOut.write('\n');
                fOut.close();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```